# AppStore App Submission

Tags: ios, app-store, submit, version

I have made an app for iOS that supported iOS 5 and above.

Later I added an update that supported iOS 6.1 and above (which is now live). Thus people with iOS versions 5.x.x and 6.0 could download the first version and those with 6.1 and above could download the second version. I accidentally uploaded a new version (third one) with support for iOS 5 and above.

And now all users are getting the third version of the app in their updates. This update is not working for iOS 5.x.x and iOS 6.0 users. I cannot rollback the update. Uploading a new version with minimum iOS 6.1 and above will not help as the iOS 5 users will continue to receive the 3rd version as the latest update.

Our new technology does not support iOS 5.x users. Hence I can't update for them. The first version used to work. What do I do? I asked Apple but they did not provide any method or idea.

I want my users using iOS 6 and below to get the first version and others to get the latest one. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you should resubmit the first version.
then you should make an other update to users having 6.1+
This is the only solution to your problem.
You can't have any other solution.
But you can also make a version that make a test on ios version to open/close the wanted feature.